# "The nested type Register cannot hide an enclosing type" when defining a nested custom annotation

Tags: java, interface, annotations

I'm defining nested custom annotations that goes like this:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Foo {

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @interface Bar {}

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @interface Foo {}

}
```

And my expected usage was:

```
@Foo.Bar
public void doStuff1(){}

@Foo.Foo
public void doStuff2(){}
```

Note that in the second nested annotation, name of the parent and child are the same, (Foo) which results the "The nested type Register cannot hide an enclosing type".

Can anybody suggest me a workaround for this please?

Comment: Is there any reason why you need both of them to be called `Foo`? Can't your annotation be like `@FooBar.Foo`?

Comment: @Codeer, This is a part of a library I'm writing to be exposed to some vendors and I can't really change the terms as I wish.